# Access an EJB through jndi lookup

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

According to the [java ee Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#girgn) one can access an `EJB` through `jndi` with:

```
java:global[/application name]/module name/enterprise bean name[/interface name]
```

I am using `Jboss` application server and when I try to access an `EJB` named `FirstBean` which implements na interface `CustomerData` with :

```
bean = (CustomerData) context.lookup("java:global/EJBTest/FirstBean/CustomerData");
```

it throws an Exception:

```
 Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

If I add the line:

```
properties.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
```

it throws an other Exception:

```
No provider URL configured for connection
```

I have achieved to access it using the `Jboss` specification as:

```
bean = (CustomerData) context.lookup("ejb:/EJBTest//FirstBean!com.al.ejbtest.CustomerData");
```

How is it possible to acccess it using the standard java ee specification and particularly only with slashes and not with an exlamation mark? Are there any environment variables need to be set?

Comment: What `Jboss` version do you use?

Comment: From where do you try to access the EJB? If you try it with an remote ejb client, than you need to check the documentation of that client. E.g https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project?_sscc=t

Answer (score 0):

additionally try this:

`properties.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099");`

Comment: No, it does not work. Even if I try the newer: jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");